# Is it correct to use an adjective before an article?

Tags: articles, adjectives, word-order, syntax

Is it correct to use an adjective before an article? For example:
**This is called a toy**
Here in this example "called" is considered as an adjective that modifies "a toy", (according to [the information provided by the Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/called)) ?

If it's correct,  please tell me why it's correct.

Comment: Called is not an adjective. It is a verb.

Comment: "Called" is a past-participle verb here, not an adjective. It has "a toy" as its direct object.

Comment: @BillJ But the Collins Dictionary shows that the word "called" is used as an adjective

Comment: I've no idea why Collins call it an adjective. No other dictionary I looked at defines it as such. It's actually a 'short passive' clause -- the kind that doesn't have a _by_ phrase, though It could be expanded to "This is called a toy by the store" where its verbal interpretation is even clearer (cf. the active "The store calls this a toy").

Comment: @BillJ - That was my first thought as well, but I looked it up on OneLook, and, behold, there was [another](https://onelook.com/?w=called&ls=a) dictionary that called it an adjective. So then I looked it up in the OED, and found an entry that said, "called, _n_. and _adj_." However, it's worth pointing out that the adjectival examples from the OED are quite different from the one in this question; they include: _It..tests to see if the **called** number is engaged._

Comment: @J.R. I disagree with the OED, In "called number", "called" is a VP functioning as a pre-head modifier. But it's academic here, since "called" is clearly a past-participle verb heading a passive VP.

Comment: @BillJ - I'm not trying to convince you; I'm just saying that I've now found **three** dictionaries that call it an adjective, not just one, so I can see why a learner might get confused.

Comment: @BoSsYyY One possible explanation for Collins calling it an adjective in (their example) _There are two men called Buckley at the Home Office_ is that some people think of participles as (always) being adjectives. They can be adjectives of course in, e.g. _It didn't look broken to me_ or _He was very frightened_ , where "broken" and "frightened" are called past-participial adjectives. But in your example, there is no doubt that "called" is a past-participial verb form.

Comment: @BoSsYyY The obvious evidence for "called" being a verb in your example is that it has the direct object "a toy". Only verbs take direct objects, never adjectives.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not an adjective. 'Call' is a complex-transitive verb that takes a direct object and a predicative complement. In this case, *a toy* is an object-oriented predicative complement describing the predicand *this*. This is hard to analyze because it's passivised, so I convert it into the active counterpart.

> They called this a toy.

This is comparable to other complex-transitive verbs like 'consider' - - "I consider that a mistake" ~ "That's considered a mistake".

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: No
Complex answer: You're wrong!

The most important thing is, *called* is not an adjective here! It's the past participle of *call*. The whole sentence is a passive voice, meaning *People call this a toy*.

***call*** is a complex-transitive verb that takes two objects, one direct and one predicative. Like these

> People **call this a toy**. (call, this, a toy)
>   I **give him my pen**.
>   He **sends me an email**.

---

For your *actual* question, the answer is *usually no with some exceptions*. One of them is in *so ... that* sentence. For example

> This is **so good a book** that I want to read it again.

But definitely not in regular sentences, where we'd place the adjective between the article and the noun:

> <s>This is good a book.</s> (No *good a book*!)
>   This is a good book.